# Scroll Bar Won't Scroll When Using Overflow: Hidden

Tags: html, css, scroll, scrollbar

I am creating a webpage, and when a button is clicked a  element containing text appears. However, the text is bigger than the div so I changed the div's css to look like this:

A scroll bar appears, but when I try scrolling, nothing happens.
Here is my HTML

```css
.exampleDiv {
  background-color: white;
  width: 96vw;
  height: 80vh;
  border-color: gray;
  border-style: solid;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

```html
<div class="exampleDiv" >
  <div class="statsheet" id="statsheet">
    <p><b>Bold</b></p>
    <p id="Text">Text</p>
    <p id="Text">Text</p>
      <p id="Text">Text</p>
      <p><b>Bold</b></p>
      <p id="skill1">Skill 1: None</p>
      <p id="skill2">Skill 2: None</p>
      <p id="skill3">Skill 3: None</p>
      <p id="skill4">Skill 4: None</p>
      <p id="skill5">Skill 5: None</p>
      <p><b>Bold</b></p>
      <p id="prof1">Prof. 1: None</p>
      <p id="prof2">Prof. 2: None</p>
      <p id="prof3">Prof. 3: None</p>
      <p id="prof4">Prof. 4: None</p>
      <p id="prof5">Prof. 5: None</p>
      <p id="prof6">Prof. 6: None</p>
      <p id="prof7">Prof. 7: None</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Add your HTML we cant help you without more details.

Comment: I added the HTML.

Comment: There is no element here with a class equal to `exampleDiv`.
it's good to have added HTML, but still it would have to correspond to the CSS code...Read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `scrollbar` is not scrolling because of `exampleDiv` div `z-index: -1;` and also its position is `relative`, so you can:

Change `exampleDiv` position to something else like `absolute`.

```
.exampleDiv {
    background-color: white;
    width: 96vw;
    height: 80vh;
    border-color: gray;
    border-style: solid;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Or remove `z-index` or set it greater or equal to 0. Like this:

**NOTE:** I removed `style="display: none;"` because it's not relevant to the question.

```css
.exampleDiv {
  background-color: white;
  width: 96vw;
  height: 80vh;
  border-color: gray;
  border-style: solid;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

```html
<div class="exampleDiv" >
    <div class="statsheet" id="statsheet" style="">
      <p><b>Bold</b></p>
      <p id="Text">Text</p>
      <p id="Text">Text/p>
        <p id="Text">Text</p>
        <p><b>Bold</b></p>
        <p id="skill1">Skill 1: None</p>
        <p id="skill2">Skill 2: None</p>
        <p id="skill3">Skill 3: None</p>
        <p id="skill4">Skill 4: None</p>
        <p id="skill5">Skill 5: None</p>
        <p><b>Bold</b></p>
        <p id="prof1">Prof. 1: None</p>
        <p id="prof2">Prof. 2: None</p>
        <p id="prof3">Prof. 3: None</p>
        <p id="prof4">Prof. 4: None</p>
        <p id="prof5">Prof. 5: None</p>
        <p id="prof6">Prof. 6: None</p>
        <p id="prof7">Prof. 7: None</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see if you set `z-index: 0;` the scroll will work, if you return it to `z-index: -1;` then the scroll will freeze.